# Django Heroku H10 error method=GET path="/favicon.ico"

Tags: django, heroku

I am fighting with this error while trying to get Django app to Heroku.

Below some details:

Requirements:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2==2.7.7
psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1
pytz==2018.9
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

WSGI:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "folder.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Procfile tried (below are options i used in separate files/deployment):

```
web: gunicorn 4_Django/folder/wsgi.py 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

LOGs:

Procfile logs:

```
2019-01-29T14:18:23.785257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `gunicorn 4_Django/folder/wsgi.py 0.0.0.0:8023`
2019-01-29T14:18:26.388317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
starting to crashed
2019-01-29T14:18:26.307448+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with 
status 3
2019-01-29T14:18:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-01-29T14:18:32.222748+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=djangozadanie.herokuapp.com request_id=7102a7b5-2798-4317-988d- 
a690c10c9a14 fwd="89.78.65.77" dyno= connect= service= status=503 
bytes= protocol=https
```

During deployment i get dozen of lines like the below, but i am not sure it has anythong to do with the problem:

```
Found another file with the destination path 'style.css'. It will be 
ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is 
not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have used runserver at all, since it is not meant for production.

Comment: Good point. Tried approx 20 options. Any other ideas ?

Comment: You need to show more of the error log for when you used gunicorn. Does it mention why it crashed? Is it the same db OperationalError as in number 3? If so you need to show your DATABASES setting. Are you using django_heroku?

Comment: @DanielRoseman addedd more details to description. Installed django_heroku, new deployment posted. Above error i still get.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use gunicorn. It accepts a Python module path, not a file path, and doesn't take an IP or port on the command line.

As [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) show, actually all you need is just:

```
web: gunicorn folder.wsgi
```

assuming `folder` is your project name.

Comment: now i get only this: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=djangozadanie.herokuapp.com request_id=3585f170-0407-495d-8dfa-e972d8ad0ea3 fwd="89.78.65.77" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https